# R - Repeated model fitting with variable deletion

Tags: r, statistics, regression, linear-regression, model-comparison

I have random sample containing 1 response variable and 10 explanatory variables (X) and I'm trying to find the best subset applying linear regression

No problems with fitting the model, but I need y^s for each subset, so I'm open to any suggestions how to discard the least significant variable and re-fit the model repeatedly until there's only constant and yet save y^ for each subset.

Don't need the whole script, that would be silly of me, i'm just looking for any useful functions.

Thank you all in advance.

Ondrej

Comment: This question is bout statistics not about programming. You should ask it in [cross validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/). Thats 's said there are many R method for variable selection (take a look at `leaps` algorithm for example).

Comment: Its **not** about stats. The Q is about how to compute `y^s` (whatever that is. y-hats? Fitted y values?) for a model and also how to drop terms from a formula. Whether this is a good method for variable selection would be a stats Q, but this isn't what was asked...

Comment: Try `step` function. It's not exactly what you need, but close ;)